# what's the difference between these two syntax? dictionary get()

Tags: python

```
def twoSum(self, num, target):
    d = {n:pos for pos, n in enumerate(num)}
    for i, n in enumerate(num):
        if d.get(target-n):   # 1
        # if target - n in d: # 2
            return (i+1, d[target-n]+1)
    return None
```

What's the difference between 1 and 2? why the result is not the same?

Comment: `why the result is not the same` - What input? What output you got?

Comment: if i use 2, i will get these results:

Comment: Input: [3,2,4], 6
Output: 1, 1
Expected: 2, 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dict.get()` returns a *default value*, `None` unless you specify something else, or the value for the key if present. You are testing if the value returned *or* `None` is a *true value*. Anything not `None` or numeric 0 or an empty container is true. See [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

This means that if the dictionary **does** have the key, but the value for that key is a 0 or an empty container or `None` or even `False`, your test fails.

The other test tests *purely* for the key. It then doesn't matter what the value associated with the key is.

Compare:

```
>>> d = {'foo': 0}
>>> d.get('foo')
0
>>> bool(d.get('foo'))
False
>>> 'foo' in d
True
```

For your specific case, the first value in `num` is always going to be given the index `0`, which is *false* when tested as a boolean:

```
>>> num = 3, 2, 4
>>> d = {n:pos for pos, n in enumerate(num)}
>>> d
{2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 2}
>>> bool(d.get(3))
False
```

Comment: That's a really odd way to create the dictionary as opposed to just writing out the dictionary literal.

Comment: @Dunes: It is called a dictionary comprehension, and I used it to show what is produced for the *input given*. The code in the original post uses a dictionary comprehension; because it is the `enumerate()` call that produces the `0` for `3` it matters here.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code:

```
if {'a': None}.get('a'):
  print "foo"
if 'a' in {'a': None}:
  print "bar"
```

Because `None` evaluates to `False`, the first example doesn't print `"foo"`. But the second example always prints `"bar"` because the key `'a'` is in the dictionary.